# npm i @socket.io/admin-ui how to fix this error?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, npm-install

```
\Server> npm i @socket.io/admin-ui
Au caractère Ligne:1 : 7
+ npm i @socket.io/admin-ui
+       ~~~~~~~
Impossible d’utiliser l’opérateur de projection «@» pour référencer des variables dans une expression. «@socket» ne peut être utilisé que comme argument     
d’une commande. Pour référencer des variables dans une expression, utilisez «$socket».
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SplattingNotPermitted
```

getting this error white trying to install socket.io admin-ui on Vscode terminal

getting this error white trying to install socket.io admin-ui on Vscode terminal

Answer (score 2):

Il faut mettre des guillements autour
La commande suivante devrait fonctionner :

```
npm i '@socket.io/admin-ui'
```